# Find all polar coordinates of point $P$ where $P = (7, \pi/3)$.

Tags: polar-coordinates

I don't know where to go from here.

Answer choices are:

a) $(7, \pi/3 + 2n\pi)$ or $(-7, \pi/3 + 2n\pi)$

b) $(7, \pi/3 + 2n\pi)$ or $(-7, \pi/3 + (2n + 1)\,\pi)$

c) $(7, \pi/3 + (2n + 1)\,\pi)$ or $(-7, \pi/3 + 2n\pi)$

d) $(7, \pi/3 + n\pi)$ or $(-7, \pi/3 + n\pi)$

Comment: Hint: For a given point in polar coordinates, you get the same point if you: (1) add a multiple of $2\pi$ to the angle, and/or (2) add $\pi$ to the angle and reverse the sign of the "distance" from the origin.

Comment: (7, pi/3 + 2npi) or (-7, pi/3 + 2npi)

Comment: Which is answer choice A.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Adding a multiple of $2\pi$ to the angle does not change the point. However, adding $\pi$ changes a point to its negative (the opposite to the origin). Replacing the "distance" to the origin with its negative also changes a point to its negative.

Therefore, for a given point in polar coordinates, you get the same point if you:

(1) add a multiple of $2\pi$ to the angle (which does no change), and/or

(2) add $\pi$ to the angle and reverse the sign of the "distance" from the origin (which takes the negative of the point twice, and results in no change).

Be careful, as adding a multiple of $2\pi$ to the angle and reversing the sign of the distance from the origin does *not* give the same point. Therefore, **a)** is *not* the correct choice. My action (2) does not add a multiple of $\pi$, just $\pi$ itself.

Can you continue from here?